Cloud Vision API のLABEL_DETECTIONは、植物の同定(種類の判定)を行なえますか？
私は、日本在住日本人のプログラミング初心者です。
PWA手法を使って、植物同定(植物種類の判定)Appを作ろうとしています。
そこで知りたいことが、
GoogleのCloud Vision API のLABEL_DETECTIONは、植物の同定(種類の判定)を行なえますか？
また、同様のAPIがあれば教えて欲しいです。

ドキュメントを見る限り、植物が映っている事は判別出来ても詳しい種類までは難しいのではないでしょうか。必要な場合には独自の学習モデルを用意する形になると思います。
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels?hl=ja
(強調は引用者によるもの)

ラベルにより、一般的な物体、場所、活動、動物の種類、商品などを識別できます。ターゲットを設定したカスタムラベルが必要な場合、Cloud AutoML Vision では、カスタム機械学習モデルをトレーニングして画像を分類できます。

